# Applying for EEA family permit to enter the UK, with marriage realized outside Europe

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, family

Is a certified translation (made in the country we live in) of the marriage certificate enough?
What are the requirements for this translation?

I'm asking this because an Italian consulate (I'm an Italian-Brazilian citizen) informed us that, to use our marriage rights in Italy, we'd need to make a "transcription" to make it valid in that country. That meant pay a fee, send the original to Italy and wait 90 days.